# Is possible to assign already created AWS Lambda to a AWS REST API Gateway Resource via Serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have 5 Rest APIs in AWS api gateway which need to share a already created AWS lambda for its resources? Manually using the console i was able to do that but i was not able to implement it in serverless framework. Is there any way possible to implement this scenario with serverless framework??

Comment: well... Serverless Framework is basically CloudFormation with plugins. You could do it by using pure CloudFormation syntax, but then you lose everything that the serverless framwork offers and defining api gateway  and your lambdas through CloudFormation is nightmarish...

Comment: What do you promise yourself by linking existing resources (APIG <-> Lambda)? Unless your services are already productive it isn't a problem to delete them in AWS and let them be created by serverless, which is definitely possible. If you want to keep the existing services, maybe renaming them to "-legacy" can help you. For a short period of time you would then have double API Gateways and Lambdas, until you switched the traffic to the new gateway and deleted the old resources.